# to run an exe file in the panel of c#.net application

Tags: .net, winforms, panel, exe

1. I want to run an exe file on my winform .net application within the panel using c# code
2. I'm able to run exe file on the button click with `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` and `Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");`  but what is the code to run this notepad file or any other exe file within the panel using c# code?
3. I want to run the application within the panel not on the separate window.i had run the following code but the exe does not stay on the screen nor it opens within the panel
   please tell me the solution for this.

   ```
       Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
       Thread.Sleep (600);  // Allow the process to open it's window 
       SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);


   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
   ```

Comment: @zoya, Did you check the article I suggested? It shows an example of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are talking about is embedding an application in your panel.

This is only possibly with executables that have been created to be embedded. Notepad is not one of those. Some browsers can be - [Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/embedding/) is one example, and [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752040%28VS.85%29.aspx) is another.

Comment: my code is opening running an exe file on the seperate window but not opening it within the panel.also the exe is not stable

Comment: exe is not stable? What does that mean?

Comment: ok then tell me the solution for running an exe within the panel means in that particular panel area not on the seperate window.
tell me by screening my code that i have given..where i have to modify?

Comment: i mean that exe is not stable on the panel of my .net program its appearing on the seperate window..i want to do embedding.

Comment: As I explained, you can't do that with applications that have not been written to do this. And `Process.Start` will _never_ do that for you. You need to find _controls_ that do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for this: [Window Tabifier](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowTabifier.aspx)

Comment: thanks for ur help...can u plz elaborate. 
i want to know that how could i navigate/toggle between the different exe files on my c# program on the button click event..basically i want to do toggling between the current and previously opened exe file..im able to run an exe file on my program but not able to provide an option for opening the previously running exe file.

Comment: can u provide me the solution for embedding the exe on the panel of my .netprogram using c#code. i dont want to execute the exe on the seperate window i want to execute it within the panel.

Comment: Just read the article. It comes with source code. I cannot do it for you.

Comment: tell me the solution for calling the third party application in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? you know that if its your own programs you want to run in the panel you could write some basic plugin code and get a control from a assembly with reflection..

Comment: thanks for ur answer but can u provide me the solution for embedding the exe on the panel of my .netprogram using c#code. i dont want to execute the exe on the seperate window i want to execute it within the panel.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is pipe the output of the exe to your process. Usually when you do not do not pipe the output it defaults to stdout for a console application will be the console window by piping you are telling the exe you want the output to come to your process not the console window. Then you would have to create your own "panel" (a multiline textbox) and append the the output stream from the exe you invoked to it!

Learn here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=VS.90).aspx