# run another EXE app as child window of WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [to run an exe file in the panel of c#.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160767/to-run-an-exe-file-in-the-panel-of-c-net-application)

it's posible to run another EXE app as child window of WinForm, in form area?

Answer (score 0):

[Yes, it is possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/31/10147981.aspx):

> It's legal to have an owner/owned relationship that crosses process boundaries. Note that when you do this, it attaches the two threads' input queues so you have to be careful if both windows process input at the same time.

Pay attention to the warning -- both processes have to co-operate here. You can't reparent arbitary applications inside your own window.