# Is it possible to open an application within a panel of a form , like Google chrome

Tags: c#, panel

I don't know its possible or not

I can open it outside individually by

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("FileName");
```

I tried this too

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace wmpkhela
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process p = Process.Start(@"notepad.exe");
            p.WaitForInputIdle();            
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle,  panel1..Handle);
        }![enter image description here][1]

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work as I expected

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowTabifier.aspx) and probably it is a duplicate see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160767/to-run-an-exe-file-in-the-panel-of-c-net-application)

Comment: Process p = Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    Thread.Sleep (600);  // Allow the process to open it's window 
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);


this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Use these two functions for placing any other process inside panels.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
public static extern IntPtr SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy, int wFlags);
```